# How to submit a selected option value to a function in controller and don't leave the view c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in controller
Eg: protected void Action(string a, string b){}
And in View i have a form to select option
When I click submit, Action() will call and parameters form this form.

```
 <form>
<select id="oto1"  class="form-control" >
<option value="" selected>An</option>
<option value="MY">Ben</option>
</select>
<select id="oto2"  class="form-control" >
<option value="" selected>Cylny</option>
<option value="de">Denny</option>
</select>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send or get something from the server without living your current view, you can also use ajax. Learn more about it [here](https://jquery.com/)

Now to achieve your goal, add this ajax code in the same view:

If your action method is using HttpPost:

```
<script>
$("#oto1").change(function () {
    let _selectedValue = $(this).val();
    let _data = {"yourParameterName": _selectedValue};
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/YourControllerName/SelectedOption",
       data: _data,
       success: function (result) {
           //Your post back logic here
        },
   });       
});
```

If your action method is using HttpGet:

```
<script>
  $("#oto1").change(function (){
   let _selectedValue = $(this).val();
   $.get( "/YourControllerName/SelectedOption?selectedValue=" + _selectedValue, 
   function( data ) {
           //Your post back logic here
    });     
 });
```

Your action method if you are using GET:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SelectedOption(string selectedValue)
{           
        return Json(YourOject);
}
```

Your action method if you are using POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SelectedOption(string selectedValue)
{           
        return Json(YourOject);
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Good answer, however this quote isn't correct strictly speaking: "Whenever you want to send or get something from the server without living your current view, you must use ajax." You can use WebSockets instead of AJAX, however I have no doubt that AJAX is the correct choice in this case.